# RefineryCMS - How do I access attributes from different engines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, refinerycms

I've created an Event engine that consists of Event date and Event description.

The admin section now has an Events tab and the frontend has an Events page, which lists all Events.

What if I want to access the Events on the home page instead? How do I go about that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your engine is Event, you could access in the front-end the data in this way:

```
Refinery::Events::Event.all # You can make your query here
```

I really recommend override the pages controller  and customise you homepage action, there you can have an instance variable to access the data at your view.

[Here](http://www.slideshare.net/AndyMaleh/rails-engine-patterns) you can find more information about engines. Check the namespace routes. Hope it helps.